# How can I cast an int to a bit in MySQL 5.1?

Tags: mysql, casting, bit, mysql-5.1

I am transitioning from SQL Server to MySQL 5.1 and seem to be tripped up trying to create a table using a select statement so that the column is a bit.

Ideally the following would work:

```
CREATE TABLE myNewTable AS
SELECT cast(myIntThatIsZeroOrOne as bit) AS myBit
FROM myOldtable
```

However sql is very unhappy at casting as a bit.  How can I tell it to select an int column (which I know only has 0s and 1s) as a bit?

Comment: Why exactly you need to cast it to bit? Can't your use [TINY]INT? According to manual casting to BIT is not possible.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You cannot!

CAST and CONVERT only work to:

- BINARY[(N)]
- CHAR[(N)]
- DATE
- DATETIME
- DECIMAL[(M[,D])]
- SIGNED [INTEGER]
- TIME
- UNSIGNED [INTEGER]

No room for: BIT, BITINT, TINYINT, MEDIUMINT, BIGINT, SMALLINT, ...

However, you can create your own function cast_to_bit(n):

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION cast_to_bit (N INT) RETURNS bit(1)
BEGIN
    RETURN N;
END
```

To try it yourself, you can create view with several conversions like:

```
CREATE VIEW view_bit AS
    SELECT
        cast_to_bit(0),
        cast_to_bit(1),
        cast_to_bit(FALSE),
        cast_to_bit(TRUE),
        cast_to_bit(b'0'),
        cast_to_bit(b'1'),
        cast_to_bit(2=3),
        cast_to_bit(2=2)
```

... and then describe it!

```
DESCRIBE view_bit;
```

Ta-dah!! Everyone is bit(1) now!!!

Answer (score 5):

Try `CONV(N,from_base,to_base)`

Converts numbers between different number bases. Returns a string representation of the number N, converted from base from_base to base to_base. Returns NULL if any argument is NULL. The argument N is interpreted as an integer, but may be specified as an integer or a string. The minimum base is 2 and the maximum base is 36. If to_base is a negative number, N is regarded as a signed number. Otherwise, N is treated as unsigned. `CONV()` works with 64-bit precision.

for example.

```
select CONV(9, 10, 2);
```

Comment: A bit is either zero or one, there is no base representation. I think you confused it with byte.

Comment: the base representation of a BIT column is 2. BIT(n)  is a series of up to (n) 1-bit digits that can be either zero or one. so you could CONV to base 2, but I don't think it would work because it sounds like the result is an INT.

Answer (score 3):

Try using case:

```
CREATE TABLE myNewTable AS
SELECT (case myIntThatIsZeroOrOne when 1 then true else false end) AS myBit
FROM myOldtable
```