# Wordpress Database Class - MySQL Type Bit

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, wordpress

I am using the WPDB object inside of Wordpress to communicate with a MySQL database. My database has a column with a type of `bit(1)`, however, Wordpress does not extract these as a `0` or `1` on my production server (they did on my local machine).

---

**Question:**

If I have a database value from Wordpress, I can't do a simple comparison to `0` or `1`:

```
if ($data[0]->Sold == 1) { //Always false
...
if ($data[0]->Sold == 0) { //Always false
```

How can I check if the value is `0` of `1`?

---

**Background:**

This was not an issue on my local machine, but only in production.

I query the database like this:

```
$data = $wpdb->get_results("...");
```

When I do a `var_dump()` on the results from the database, here is the output my browser shows:

```
array(1) {
  [0] => object(stdClass)#261 (10) {
    ["SaleID"]     => string(4) "1561"
    ["BookID"]     => string(2) "45"
    ["MerchantID"] => string(1) "1"
    ["Upload"]     => string(19) "2012-11-20 15:46:15"
    ["Sold"]       => string(1) ""
    ["Price"]      => string(1) "5"
    ["Condition"]  => string(1) "5"
    ["Written"]    => string(1) ""
    ["Comments"]   => string(179) "<p>I am the first owner of this barely used book. There aren't any signs of normal wear and tear, not even any creases on the cover or any of its pages. It would pass for new.</p>"
    ["Expiring"]   => string(19) "2013-05-20 15:46:15"
  }
}
```

Notice how `Sold` and `Written` show a string size of `1`, but don't have an associated value. These values should be populated with `1` and `0`, respectively.

The Chrome inspector tool shows something quite interesting for these values:

[image]

[image]

What is `\u1` or `\u0` and why aren't they simply `1` or `0`, so I can do comparisons?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: It sounds like the values are not set in the mySQL database.
Try updating the rows in mySQL.

Comment: @fredrik I had mentioned: "These values should be populated with `1` and `0`, respectively."

Comment: Well `\u1` and `\u0` is content, unfortunately the unicode representation of control characters. Maybe you could try to cast them to an integer.

Comment: Yet you say "should", not are. That implies a possibility that they are incorrectly populated. Also providing the table definition might help.

Comment: @feeela I will try that. Do you know why on my development server this was not an issue?

Comment: @fredrik Sorry, you're right about that. They do have the values of 1 and 0. ;)

Comment: It could have to do with different DB setups (i.e. MySQL Version).
You could also try to [cast the value to int using MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6918897/how-can-i-cast-an-int-to-a-bit-in-mysql-5-1).

Comment: Then I'm guessing that you have programmatially added a 1 or 0 char, not a string containing 1 or 0. which would explain the `\u0` and `\u1`. meaning: you have put a `0` or `1` in the row, not a `"0"` or `"1"`. big difference.

Comment: @fredrik That really could be the reason. [at]spryno724 See also the MySQL docs: [»To specify bit values, b'value' notation can be used. value is a binary value written using zeros and ones. For example, b'111' and b'10000000' represent 7 and 128, respectively.«](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/bit-type.html)

Comment: @feeela @fredrik Thank you both. You could have been correct with me putting the values in as chars. I simply converted the type `bit(1)` to `tinyint(1)` and all has worked fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this answer out:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5323169/794897

"When you select data from a MySQL database using PHP the datatype will always be converted to a string."

You can either do:

```
if ($data[0]->Sold === "1") { 
...
if ($data[0]->Sold === "0") {
```

or type cast the variable, e.g.

```
$Sold = (int) $data[0]->Sold;

if ($Sold === 1) { 
...
if ($Sold === 0) {
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to use ord function: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php

**Edit**

Yet the behavior seems to differ depending on the server. On Arch Linux with MariaDB 10.0.14 and Ubuntu with MySQL 5.5.37-0ubuntu0.13.10.1 *wpdb* returns good old "0" or "1" strings, not the problematic bit-strings, which happen on CentOS 6.4 MySQL 5.1.73