# Display TINYINT as INT instead of TRUE FALSE

Tags: mysql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I am selecting a `TINYINT` column from MySQL database, it will display properly in MySQL, but when I print the value in the report using SSRS, it will display the value as `True` or `False` instead of its original value in number. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/289759/4541141),  it evaluates the `TINYINT` which has value not equal to 0 to `true`, `false` otherwise, but in this case, I don't want it to be like this.

Since it is unable to convert or cast `TINYINT` to `INT` in MySQL ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20181971/4541141)), is there any simple workaround other than changing the column datatype to `INT`?

**UPDATE**
The column will not have 0 and 1 as value only, it might be any non-zero value which supports by `TINYINT`.

**Value displayed in MySQL GUI**
[image: Value displayed in MySQL GUI]

**Value displayed in SSRS**
[image]

Comment: Go to textbox properties and select Number. What is selected there?

Comment: It seems the problem is with mysql giving SSRS a bit datatype instead of tinyint. SSRS treats tinyint like any other numeric data type. Only bit datatypes are presented as True/False values and unfortunately conversion doesn't work in this case

Comment: Can you not cast the tinyint to int in the SSRS dataset sql? Or create a mysql view with the value cast to int and use that instead of reading the table direct?

Comment: @AB_87 Tried both `Default` and `Number`, none of these working.

Comment: @niktrs Your assumption make sense, but do you have any idea to deal with it?

Comment: @MandyShaw the `Cint()` function will not work in this case, it will returns `-1`. Again, MySQL cannot use CAST for `TINYINT`

Comment: The only option if possible is to fix it at the database level to make SSRS get a  tinyint value data type instead of bit

Comment: @Newbie can you cast tinyint to a character value in mysql? (Seems to me you are going to have problems with this column in other places than just SSRS, by the way.)

Comment: Maybe what MandyShaw suggesting could be a good workaround. Convert to string then use Cint in SSRS to convert it to integer

Comment: It works! Thanks for the idea. It is true that MySQL cannot cast the value to INT, but it actually can cast to `SIGNED` or `UNSIGNED`. So my case can be simply solved by `CONVERT(column, UNSIGNED)` since the column will only have non-zero value