# Error with "insert '0' in bit-field type"

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb

Why does `INSERT '0'` in [*bit(1)*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/bit/), produce an error:

> #1406 - Data too long for column [del] at row [del].

If I `INSERT 0` (like int) everything is fine. Why doesn't the field want to automatically convert the string to an integer?

Comment: it's the same reason why a string cannot be casted to a bit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6918897/how-can-i-cast-an-int-to-a-bit-in-mysql-5-1

Comment: @Luuk Strange logic. This is sad.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
INSERT '0'='0';
INSERT '0'='1';
```

to insert resp. `true` and `false`.

Comment: I use SQL in php, and 0 for bit, this is an array element: 
$bar['foo'] = "0";

$stmt->bindParam(':foo', $bar['foo']);

Answer (score 0):

Single quotes are for literals, here is a great explanation

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14123649/5754159

Comment: If I write "1" the result is the same