# Stuck at making a property of the view to appear as bit(1) in my MariaDB view

Tags: mariadb

I want to add a calculation column to my MariaDB view to return true/false. However, no matter what I do and how I cast it, its data type is always int.

As an example, consider this view:

```
create view Sample
as
select 1 as IsShipped
```

When you look at the structure it's `int`:

[image]

Now I want to force that column to be boolean:

```
alter view Sample
as
select cast(1 as bit) as IsShipped
```

It doesn't compile. It gives me this error:

> Error in query (1064): Syntax error near 'bit(1)) as IsShipped' at line 3

And If I use `if`:

```
alter view Sample
as
select if(1,true,false) AS IsShipped
```

It still has the `int` data type.

What should I do? I want its data type to become `bit(1)`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I cast an int to a bit in MySQL 5.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6918897/how-can-i-cast-an-int-to-a-bit-in-mysql-5-1)

Answer (score 0):

You can't [`CAST`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/cast/) to bit.

From docs :

> The type can be one of the following values:
>
> ```
> BINARY
> CHAR
> DATE
> DATETIME
> DECIMAL[(M[,D])]
> DOUBLE
> FLOAT (from MariaDB 10.4.5)
> INTEGER
> Short for SIGNED INTEGER
> SIGNED [INTEGER]
> UNSIGNED [INTEGER]
> TIME
> VARCHAR (in Oracle mode, from MariaDB 10.3)
> ```

However, you can create your own function cast_to_bit(n):

```
CREATE FUNCTION cast_to_bit (N INT) RETURNS bit(1)
BEGIN
    RETURN N;
END
```

Then you can alter the view like :

```
ALTER VIEW Sample
AS
SELECT cast_to_bit(1) as IsShipped;
```

Then if you describe it : `DESCRIBE Sample;` you will get :

```
Field    |Type  |Null|Key|Default|Extra|
---------+------+----+---+-------+-----+
IsShipped|bit(1)|YES |   |       |     |
```